# Call methods from a very complicated C++ Win32 DLL with tons of classes by Java process via JNA

Tags: java, c++, dll, jna

I have a very complicated and big DLL written in C++ for Win32 by developers from other departments, which need to be used by my java-processes. What I have:

**Restrictions:** I'm not allowed (though I have a .sol file) to make any changes to that DLL.

**Goal:** I want my java-processes to be able to call some methods from this DLL.

**Instruments:** First I want to try it with JNA (second witn JNI).

**Problem:**

I read some general information about JNA and understood, that first you build prototypes of methods you want to call in the interface. Good, the question now is following: methods, which I want to call, take self-defined objects from DLL project as parameters. For example I have a function in DLL like:

```
__declspec(dllexport) BOOL WINAPI NiceFunction( 
          Dummy_State *ModuleState, Dummy_Handle Handle, Dummy_Exception &Exception,
          LPCTSTR name, DWORD timer);
```

Where all `Dummy_` objects are of classes, defined in this DLL.

**Question 1:** how to call with JNA such functions in my java process?

**Question 2:** is it possible to use those objects somehow direct in my java process? Maybe to import somehow the constructor? However the constructors of those objects require often to call constructors of parent class(es).

**Question 3:** last but not least, my DLL also called two additional DLLs and widely used a data from them (some of `Dummy_` objects). Do I need also to import (somehow) them in my java process via JNA or not?

Comment: `Dummy_Exception &Exception` -- This is a parameter in an `extern C` function?  References should not be used as a parameter type for such functions.  You are basically tied to the same compiler, compiler version, compiler options, etc. that built the DLL.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, oh, you are right, I have just copied this from google automatically as an example, didn't notice it. Of course, there is no need for extern "C" actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNA only works with C functions, not C++.  The only C++ functions you'll be able to map must have been externalized with `extern "C"`.  If they are not, and you are unable to change the DLL, you may have to write your own DLL wrapper which has `extern "C"` versions.

**How to call with JNA such functions:**

You must map them to a Java interface.  For example:

```
public interface ComplicatedAndBigLibrary {
    // Create an instance to access the mapped functions with
    // the String in quotes is the filename, minus .dll
    ComplicatedAndBigLibrary INSTANCE = 
        (ComplicatedAndBigLibrary) Native.load("compbiglib", W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    // Map the C structures or typedefs
    // Use "extends" as needed for parents
    @FieldOrder({"field1", "field2"})
    class Dummy_State extends Structure {
        // map structure fields here
        public int field1;
        public byte field2;
    }

    class Dummy_Handle extends WinNT.HANDLE {
        // any overrides you need
    }

    // Map your functions (that were externalized)
    boolean NiceFunction( 
          Dummy_State ModuleState, Dummy_Handle Handle, Dummy_Exception ExceptionPointer,
          LPCTSTR name, DWORD timer);
}
```

Take a look at the JNA [source code in the `com.sun.jna.platform.win32` package](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32) for many types of examples based on Windows DLLs. You're essentially doing the same thing for your DLL.

**Use those objects somehow direct in my java process**

```
ComplicatedAndBigLibrary CABL = ComplicatedAndBigLibrary.INSTANCE;
CABL.NiceFunction(foo, bar, ...)
```

**Also called two additional DLLs and widely used a data from them**

You'll need to map the other DLL's similarly (create an interface, use `Native.load()` and map functions/constants/etc.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a reallly helpful answer! Still have two questions though, will be really thankful if you have time to answer:


**Question 4:** If I understood correctly, you may do the following: write one function, which will do all the stuff inside .cpp file of .dll library, wrap it with extern "C" and the call via JNA? I know that it is a bad practice though...


**Question 5:** in order to wrap the whole class do I have only to add one factory function to .cpp file of .dll or do I need to fully recreate my class with struct in wrapper.h, changing all referencies with ptrs?

Comment: Also there is one more general **Question 6:** if you want to map some class, which **1)** inherits some other classes, **2)** has a field of type from those inherited classes (or even the parents of those inherited) how then to wrap such stuff with struct in C? Do you have some dummy example for that? As far as I understood the idea, you are not decorating the code as it is written in C, you actually made the part of your C++ code _really_written in C. And it would be really painful to rewrite all of the 50+ classes in that DLL, which have a complicated inheritance scheme, as simple C-structs

Comment: Q4: Yes you can write a "C" function that calls whatever you need to call in C++, then compile that DLL.   You can then reference your "C" DLL from JNA.   [There is an example here.](https://github.com/remram44/java-cpp-example). Note for the same amount of effort you could access the C++ code using JNI, which may be preferable from a performance standpoint.

Comment: Q5: You only need to wrap functions that you need access to in Java as methods.  The structure is just a definition of a memory layout and you can write those in JNA without needing any sort of mapping, you're just passing pointers around.  For example say you have `struct foo` in C++, and you have a C++ method `bar(foo)` that internally calls another function `baz()`, but you never have to call `baz()` yourself.  You can just map `foo` directly in Java, but you will have to write an `extern "C"` wrapper for `bar()`.  You do not need to wrap `baz()`.

Comment: Q6: You don't need to worry about the `struct`s.  You can map those in Java, you're just defining memory layout.  The only thing you generally need to wrap are the functions that you want to access as methods.   You might consider using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to automate all this for you.